# Using an object in an anonymous settimeout javascript function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to remove the clicked element from the page after a certain amount of time (1.5 seconds).
Here is the code (including some background info):

```
function AttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler)
    } else {
        element['on' + type] = handler;
    }
}

AttachEvent(window, "load", function() {

    AttachEvent(mydiv, "click", do_stuff); 
});

function do_stuff(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;  

    //some stuff        

    //remove object
    setTimeout('target.parentNode.removeChild(element);', 1500);
}
```

Internet Explorer complains about target being undefined in the anonymous function.
How do I set this timeout in Internet Explorer?

Comment: What is `element` in `setTimeout('target.parentNode.removeChild(element);', 1500);`?

Comment: I don't know. I must have overlooked that when I initially inserted the code into my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a string for `setTimeout`. [Just don't](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html). Instead pass an anonymous function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxttX/1/)):

```
function do_stuff(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;  

    //some stuff        

    //remove object
    setTimeout(function(){target.parentNode.removeChild(target);}, 1500);
}
```

If you use the function above, the current value of `target` will be used inside of the anonymous function. If you pass a string, your browser looks for a *global* object named `target`, which will fail, since target a function scope variable.